# Loading indicator for two different SPFx webpart in Same Classic Page or Workbench.aspx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

We have developed two webpart and both fetching the data from Term store so it take some time to load the data into the webpart.

if i add only one webpart to Workbench.aspx or Classic pages it displays the loading indicator and wait till data fetch and webpart render to the page.but once i added both webpart together in Workbench.aspx or classic page only one loading indicator displayed for the first webpart in sequence.

I wanted to have both webparts should display loading indicator as i am going to use these webparts in classic pages where we have separate webpart Zones. let me know if this is possible.

Comment: What does your code look like?  If you add one at a time, do each of them work correctly?  If you add both, but alternate which is added first, does anything change?

Comment: its a SharePoint JSOM call to get the Terms from Taxonomy store. If i add one at a time, each works fine. but when i add both , the first webpart alone in sequence has the loading indicator.